# Flask app - query parameters dropping out of request args

Tags: bash, curl, httpie

I have a simple Flask app (Flask version `1.0.3`) with a single app. URL  `/ask` and handler to process a POST query string of (name, value) pairs, but the `request.args` object is not storing all the parameter pairs, only the first pair. Why are the others dropping out?

I've already tried printing out the `request.args` object but it only shows the first parameter pair.

Here's the Flask app

```py
import json

from flask import (
    Flask,
    jsonify,
    request,
    Response
)


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return jsonify(message="Hello, World!")


@app.route('/ask', methods=['POST'])
def ask():
    return str(request.args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Here's the simple query, using the `http` CLI tool, with two parameters and the response args - note the response args only contains the first parameter

```
$ http POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ask?q1=name&q2=address
[1] 58720
[2019-06-12 15:29:27 $ HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 14:29:27 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.4 Python/3.6.2

ImmutableMultiDict([('q1', 'name')])
```

I get the same result using `curl`

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/nest?q1=name&q2=address
```

Is there something I'm missing

Answer (score 5):

In the shell "&" is a keyword and must be quoted. In both of your examples, everything after "&" is executed as a second command. Change your test to:

```
http POST "http://127.0.0.1:5000/ask?q1=name&q2=address"
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess quoting just the parameter string will also work.