# Python Flask not parsing GET arguments passed to route

Tags: python, flask, curl

Here is my simple code:

```py
from Flask import request

@app.route("/pods", methods=["GET"])
def list_pods():
    cluster = request.args.get("cluster")
    project = requests.args.get("project_name")
    
    print(cluster)
    print(project)
```

Running the following two cURL commands results in the second-defined variable to not get parsed:

```bash
$ curl localhost:51918/pods?cluster=nw-dc-blah&project_name=my_project
nw-dc-blah
None
```

```bash
$ curl localhost:51918/pods?project_name=my_project&cluster=nw-dc-blah
None
my_project
```

How can I get Flask to parse both GET arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Flask app - query parameters dropping out of request args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564922/flask-app-query-parameters-dropping-out-of-request-args)

The cURL URL will need to have quotes around it to escape the `&` sign, as my Unix shell doesn't parse anything after that and send it to Flask.

```bash
$ curl "localhost:51918/pods?cluster=nw-dc-blah&project_name=my_project
nw-dc-blah"
```

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce your example:

```
hello.py
 from flask import Flask,request
 
 app = Flask(__name__)
 
 @app.route("/pods", methods=["GET"])
 def list_pods():
     cluster = request.args.get("cluster")
     project = request.args.get("project_name")
 
     print(cluster)
     print(project)
     return "hello"

Then
flask --app hello run
```

Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘`"`’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes

USE (`"`) else following:

```
➜  stackoverflow curl localhost:5000/pods?cluster=nw-dc-blah&project_name=my_project
[1] 96485
zsh: no matches found: localhost:5000/pods?cluster=nw-dc-blah
[1]  + 96485 exit 1     curl localhost:5000/pods?cluster=nw-dc-blah                                                 
➜  stackoverflow curl "localhost:5000/pods?cluster=nw-dc-blah&project_name=my_project"
hello%
```